# Laravel 5 display structure of tree in view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have little problem. I have 3 tables in the database:

1. Directory 
   [image]
2. Directory_relations
   [image]
3. Videos 
   (here is data about video: name,size) this data should be print in directory where this video is added.

My question is how I have print it in view.
Structure of this should look like:

[image]

Of course can be a lot of subfolder.

THAKS!

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I have only for print VIDEO list, is simple foreach. I don't know how to display video list inside folders.

Comment: this is not a simple problem, this is a traverse tree problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: I know, that's why I am writing here

Comment: Please show us your Eloquent model relationships.

Comment: `$vid = Auth::user()->videos()->join('directory_relations', 'directory_relations.id_video', '=', 'videos.id')->orderBy($order, $how)->paginate(15);`
`$dir = Directory::select('directory_relations.*','directory.*')->join('directory_relations', 'directory_relations.id_directory', '=', 'directory.id')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();`